# Efficiently Find Page Max Dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently running a script on a third-party page to determine the maximum dimensions of the page. At first, this may seem as if I could just use `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()` on my parent wrapper, `#base` but the problem is that the page wrapper isn't sized from its children. So I might have a parent that is 0x0 and its child is 400x400 and a child inside of that which is 500x500. It seems they just allow overflow. I have tried some CSS tricks in attempt to force the parent `#base` to size itself correctly, but the children don't seem to drive this change and modifying their CSS causes actual alignment issues on the page. Additionally, there are many hidden items on the page that do not become visible until later or during page interaction so this further prevents me from just grabbing the outer dimensions of `#base` or something like that.

My current approach is to iterate through every single element on the page. I check to see where it is positioned and what its dimensions are. Based on those, I update my maximum dimensions. I also have to check for horizontal and vertical scrolling elements because those may be on the page too. If a wrapper is 500px wide and the child has a width of 1000px, but is scrolled, I wouldn't want that to affect my maximum dimensions. Anyways, this approach works but it's slow. Sometimes the page may have +15k elements. With these numbers, it takes 10 seconds on my machine. I might be able to optimize some of the conditional statements to use booleans instead of evaluating values, but I don't think this will make a significant difference. I'm hoping there is some process I'm completely overlooking. Below is my current code snippet and a demo showing how the page looks prior to running the code and after the code has been run.

Demo: https://p826ni.axshare.com/#g=1&p=without_code

```
$('#base *').not('script, style').each(function () {
    currentElement = $(this);

    // Initialize on first loop.
    if (parentElementHorizontal === undefined && parentElementVertical === undefined) {
        parentElementHorizontal = currentElement;
        parentElementVertical = currentElement;
    }

    width = currentElement.outerWidth();
    height = currentElement.outerHeight();
    scrollWidthHidden = currentElement[0].scrollWidth;
    scrollHeightHidden = currentElement[0].scrollHeight;
    top = currentElement.offset().top;
    left = currentElement.offset().left;

    // Check if we're still within the parent containing horizontal-scrolling overflow.
    if (!$.contains(parentElementHorizontal[0], currentElement[0])) {
        hiddenWidth = false;
    }

    // Check if we're still within the parent containing vertical-scrolling overflow. 
    if (!$.contains(parentElementVertical[0], currentElement[0])) {
        hiddenHeight = false;
    }

    // Check if we've found an element with horizontal-scrolling content. 
    if (!hiddenWidth) {
        maxWidth = maxWidth < left + width ? left + width : maxWidth;
    } else if (currentElement.width() > maxWidth) {
        currentElement.addClass('redline-layer');
    }
    if (scrollWidthHidden > width && !hiddenWidth && width > 0) {
        hiddenWidth = true;
        parentElementHorizontal = currentElement;
    }

    // Check if we've found an element with vertical-scrolling content. 
    if (!hiddenHeight) {
        maxHeight = maxHeight < top + height ? top + height : maxHeight;
    } else if (currentElement.height() > maxHeight) {
        currentElement.addClass('redline-layer');
    }
    if (scrollHeightHidden > height && !hiddenHeight && height > 0) {
        hiddenHeight = true;
        parentElementVertical = currentElement;
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this something where using the vw and vh CSS units is ineffective? ie. `width: 100vw ;` for full viewport width

Comment: You are correct. The goal is not to size the parent element to the dimensions of the viewport. With all of the content, it may be smaller or larger than the viewport dimensions. I added a demo to demonstrate my desired outcome.

Comment: Is there a css rule defining the page width with respect to the browser dimensions?  Maybe you can start with $(window).width() and $(window).height() and work down?

Comment: The way the page is rendered offers no clues to what its maximum dimensions may be. Sometimes I can infer the width, but not always, and I can never find an accurate height. The problem is that all of this markup and CSS is computer-generated and therefore doesn't really follow best practices.